# Change Data using Date Slider in Bokeh

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

In Bokeh, I am trying to change the visualized data by using a slider. The interesting part is, on slider change, the `console` logs the expected values but the visualization is not updated as expected.

How can I get my desired functionality?
Why is the code logging the right data but the graph is not being updated?

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.resources import CDN
import pandas as pd

df_str = '''2020-09-10 1 75731 0
2020-09-10 2 71627 0
2020-09-10 3 66972 0
2020-09-10 4 63718 0
2020-09-10 5 61951 0
2020-09-11 1 59380 1
2020-09-11 2 58297 1
2020-09-11 3 57833 1
2020-09-11 4 55669 1
2020-09-11 5 55281 1'''

df = pd.DataFrame([col.split() for col in [row for row in df_str.split('\n')]])
df.columns = ['Date', 'Score', 'ScoreTotal', 'DayNumber']

dates = df.Date.unique()

xs = [[] for _ in range(len(dates))]
ys = [[] for _ in range(len(dates))]
date = [i for i in range(len(dates))]

for _, row in df.iterrows():
  i = int(row.DayNumber)
  xi = row.Score
  yi = row.ScoreTotal
  xs[i].append(xi)
  ys[i].append(yi)

x = xs[0]
y = ys[0]
xs += [[]] * 3
ys += [[]] * 3

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, xs=xs, ys=ys))

plot = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

date_slider = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=0, step=1, title="Date Slider")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, date_slider=date_slider),
                    code="""
    const data = source.data;
    const date = date_slider.value
    const x = data['xs'][date]
    const y = data['ys'][date]
    console.log(y) // CORRECT CONSOLE LOG BUT NO CHANGE
    source.change.emit();
""")

date_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

from bokeh.layouts import column, row

layout = row(
    plot,
    column(date_slider),
)

show(layout)
```

Comment: What do you expect to change? Your code doesn't change any data, it just creates local constants `x` and `y`.

Comment: If you want to filter data based on the value of the slider, consider using filters: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#filtering-data

Comment: @EugenePakhomov, the code is supposed to change the values in the visualization too. It appears that `source.change.emit()` does the heavy lifting in terms of updating the visualization because the visualization is updated with similar JS logic on another piece of code; all we need to do is instantiate the variables. I think my issue might be indexing into the data.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov, I appreciate the suggestion of using filters! I would like to add new data not necessarily filter the data that is already there. For example, when the slider is at 0, only Day 0 data is shown. When the slider is moved to 1, Day 1 data replaced the previous data.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov, I think you may be right with your first comment. I opened a request on Bokeh side. https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/slider-not-updating-visualization/6372 A person said the same thing that you did. I will followup here when I find an answe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a [Bokeh Discourse website](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/slider-not-updating-visualization/6372/3), I was able to get a user to explain that my JS code was not modifying anything, as Eugene also mentioned in the comments above. The original data array needed to be modified in place. Updating the `code` parameter lead to the desired result:

```
  code="""
    const data = source.data;
    const date = date_slider.value;
    const old_y = data['y'];
    const x = data['xs'][date];
    const y = data['ys'][date];

    for (var i = 0; i < old_y.length; i++) {
      old_y[i] = y[i]
    }

    source.change.emit();
  """
```